# Does a teapot burst more easily when filled with water?

Tags: home-experiment, free-fall, shock-waves

This question arises from an (unlucky) incident at home. My family then went on arguing over whether our teapot would still exist in one piece if it had been empty, instead of filled with hot water.

The physical trade-off I can think of here is:

- A full teapot makes it more dense, thus increasing its falling speed a tiny bit.
- The water in a full teapot could act as a shock buffer.

Are these points valid / critical to the solution? Are there other factors to consider?

Comment: The "increasing its falling speed" is definitely not significant. Assuming your teapot isn't made of aerogel or something ;)

Comment: Your question does not describe what happened, and leaves the reader looking for clues as to what your talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fracturing of objects is a complex business, but as a general guide yes your teapot is more likely to fracture if it is full of water. The main reason is that shock waves from the impact will be efficiently transmitted through the water.

We'll do our usual physicists approximation and consider the teapot as a sphere. Consider what happens when the sphere hits the ground:

[image: Empty sphere]

When the sphere hits the ground there is an upwards force exerted on the part of the sphere that touches the ground. However spheres are very good at redistributing stresses - this after all why domes are so commonly used in buildings. So the sphere will be able to survive a considerable force.

But now fill the sphere with water:

[image: Full sphere]

There are two big differences:

1. the water in the sphere makes the sphere a lot heavier, so the force exerted by the ground in stopping the sphere is a lot larger
2. the force from the impact with the ground is transmitted through the water and bursts the sphere from the inside

Let's consider (1). The force when the sphere hits the ground is given by the rate of change of momentum. If the mass of the sphere is $m$ and the velocity of the sphere just before it hits the ground is $v$ then the momentum change when it hits the ground and stops is $mv$. If the sphere takes a time $t$ to stop, then the average force is:

$$ F = \frac{mv}{t} $$

When you fill the sphere with water you make it a lot heavier so the mass $m$ in our equation increases, and that makes the force bigger. The increase in the force makes the sphere more likely to fracture.

Now consider (2). As I mentioned spheres are pretty good at distributing stresses so they can support a high load. But when the sphere is full of water the force of the impact is distributed through the water as a pressure wave (a shock wave) and this applies a force to the walls of the sphere from the inside - I've drawn arrows to illustrate how the pressure is redistributed. Spheres aren't good at resisting forces from the inside, so this internal force will be able to fracture the sphere more easily than a force applied to the outside of the sphere.

All of which is very well, but I suppose we need to abandon our spherical approximation and return to your teapot. The question is which of these factors is more important. And the answer is that I don't know - I would have to do some teapot smashing experiments to find out. However I would guess that the teapot was only partially full, and as a result the pressure wave transmitted through the water would just make the water inside splash into the empty space rather than fracturing the teapot. My guess is that it's the increased impact force due to the increased mass of a full teapot that is mostly to blame.

Comment: [Why does a glass bottle completely filled with water not break when hit on a nail?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302591/why-does-a-glass-bottle-completely-filled-with-water-not-break-when-hit-on-a-nai).  Also, [many smashing experiments on the interweb](https://www.google.ca/search?q=does+a+full+bottle+break+more+easily).

Comment: if the water in the teapot is hot and has only been in the pot a brief time, the interior of the pot's walls will be thermally expanding before the exterior of the pot's walls have a chance to do so. This (transient) thermal stress will place the exterior surface of the pot wall in a state of tension, and if the pot is made of ceramic, it will more easily fracture. You can break brittle materials on purpose by means of this technique.